# filtering in nested for loops (django templates)

Tags: django, templates, filter, foreign-keys, nested-loops

I have two models, books and genres.

```
class Book(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
     author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     year = models.IntegerField()
     genre = models.ForeignKey('Genre', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Genre(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

On my webpage, I want to display each genre, and within each genre, only the books whose year is 1950 or later.  The code in my template looks like this:

```
{% for genre in genres %}
     <h1> {{genre.title}} </h1>
     {% for book in genre.book_set.all %}
          {{book.title}}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem with this is that it shows ALL of the books in that genre, and not just the books published after 1950.  Is it possible to filter the result of genre.book_set.all in some way to get only those that match a certain attribute?

**Edit 1**

My views look like this:

```
def books_home(request):
    books = Book.objects.filter(year__gt='1950')
    genres = Genre.objects.all()
    return render(request, "index.html", {"books": books, "genres": genres})
```

I.e. I am trying to filter out books at this stage, but it not pulling through to the template.

Comment: Hi Andrew, could you update this to show your view code? as it looks like an issue in the context that you're passing in to the template. What you have in your view looks fine. I just wouldn't do it that way pass in the context.

Comment: Done.  Sorry, I should have included this in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've marked an answer as correct but it's really not the right answer as per my comments under it. @wfehr gives you a better solution,  although that's a very short answer, and based on your question, I suspect you need more detail.

```
class Book(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
     author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     year = models.IntegerField()
     genre = models.ForeignKey('Genre', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Genre(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Your models are fine, however could be improved in the following ways:

in the `Book` class change:

```
class Book(models.Model):    
    ...
    genre = models.ForeignKey('Genre', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="books")
    ...
```

By adding this related name you'll be able to do a reverse lookup using the `Genre`, for example:

```
myGenre.books.all()
```

This would give you all the books in that genre.

Anyway, I digress.

In your `View.py` that returns the template, rather than have that logic in your template as per the answer you've marked as correct, simply filter the query set there for the exact information you want to to display.

I imagine currently you have something that looks like this in your view:

```
render("template.html", {genres=Genre.objects.all()})
```

rather than `Genre.objects.all()`, use the `Book` and reverse `Book`:

```
Book.objects.order_by('-genre').filter(year__gte=1950)
```

This way you will only get the books you actually want. `gte` is "greater than or equal to"; if you just want after 1950, then change it to `year__gt`.

Also, if you only need the book's title and genre you could do:

```
Book.objects.order_by('-genre').filter(year__gte=1950).values_list("title", pk)
```

You're only using the title, but you can specify any model field you want.

The solution above doesn't split it up by `Genre`s so you'd need to do a little more there. You can do that with `annotate` instead of a value list [further reading here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) or you could simply fetch genres first and do the following:

(N.B.: using `annotate` would reduce the DB calls to 1, but depending on number of genres this might not be an issue:

```
books = {}
for genre in Genre.objects.all().order_by('-title'):
     books[genre.title] = Book.objects.order_by('-genre').filter(year__gte=1950, genre=genre).values_list("title")
```

Using `order_by('-title')` just ensures that we get some order in the genres -- in this case alphabetical.

Then you can just return `context=books` or add it to your current context object, then adjust your template accordingly with something like this:

```
{% for key, values in books.items %}
    <h1> {{key}} </h1>
    {% for book in values %}
        {{book}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endear%}
```

By doing it this way you're not querying the DB for each book, and you're not filtering in the template.

One more thing before I go, if you don't plan on enabling users to add genres, i.e. they are predetermined, you could do away with the `Genre` Model entirely swapping the `genre` field on the `Book` model for simply

```
genres = (
("scf", "SciFi)",
("hrr", "Horror"),
("rom","Romance"),
("gen", "General"),
)
genre = models.CharField(choices=genres, default="gen", max_length=3)
```

I've added that just for reference; using the model is better if you need to add genres, or if you're gonna have a lot of them.

Comment: dude he is still in the learning phase! I had told about the views optimization is better. And he just got to know about conditional statements. So I ask you to reconsider the downvote if you had done it. Thanx

Comment: Ok, that was an amazing answer, thank you!  I had no idea you could pass a dict through the views return function.  I'm going to make this the accepted answer, but I think you should take off the downvote on @DeekshithAnand's post, because for a beginner like me it was pretty informative too :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to do the filtering in your view, not the template itself.
There you can use all of djangos features and you don't need to implement custom tags/filters for the template.
Then you can also do query-optimizations with select_/prefetch_related later on (if you are getting more queries).

Example:

```py
class myview(...):
    qs = Genre.objects.filter(book_set__year__gt=1950)
    ...
```

Also see the field-lookups in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) for filtering with `gt`.

Comment: Ok, but how do I limit the nested for loop to just the filtered books?  I still have to use the backward relationship statement {% for book in genre.book_set.all %} to get books of the relevant genre, but this statement brings all of the books of this genre.  I can't filter these at the views stage ...